# "stock.picking.out" and "stock.picking.in" are missing in Odoo 8

Tags: webkit, odoo

I am using **Odoo 8**. In order to use Webkit to custom my invoices, I have to install the "Invoice to Picking Relation" module (technical name: picking_invoice_rel). However, when I try to install this module, I discover that the **stock.picking.out** and **stock.picking.in** models are missing. 
These models were afforded by the stock module in OpenERP 7.
Could someone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

@Zoumourrouda

Yes you are right new WMS in v8 has removed the `stock.picking.out` and `stock.picking.in` object that sad part but good part was those both object were _inherits from `stock.picking` object so you can create sme report on `stock.picking` object and  you an use `picking_type_id.code` field to check this is `supplier` or `customer` or `internal` picking and create report label according.

and Moreover you can migrate your `stock.picking.out` and `stock.picking.in` data on `stock.picking` table and you wll still have all data. (NOTE" BECAREFULL WHILE DOING MIGRATION TO MESH UP ;))

Thanks